# Alinhamento do número de respostas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

É de mim ou está aqui qualquer coisa mal?

Parece-me que os quadrados estão maiores ou os outros mais pequenos...

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O comportamento ainda se mantém:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Bah... Pior que fui conferir... Muito bem visto Jorge

Comment: É por causa do 's' do plural. 'Resposta' com uma resposta, no singular, os quadrados são menores.

Comment: Bem visto @Earendul

Answer (score 10):

Não resolve o problema, esta resposta é apenas para apontar aonde ele está.

Isto ocorre por que `.narrow .cp` usa `float` e neste CSS:

```
.narrow .status {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  min-width: 44px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

Ele usa `min-width: 44px;` (então pode redimensionar a largura) e `padding` e mesmo que o texto fosse divido por um espaço, não aconteceria a quebra do texto pois o DIV está usando `display: inline-block;` o que faz o texto ampliar o DIV, a não ser que o elemento "pai" tive-se usando um `width` fixo.

Este problema ocorre por que nas comunidades de idioma em inglês os textos usados são `answer` e `answers` que cabem dentro destes `44px` e a palavra `respostas` ultrapassa este limite.

Comment: Devolvi os comentários para o lugar de origem, desbloqueei a outra pergunta, abri essa e fechei aquela como duplicada dessa.